# Could we appreciate Newton ring effects on a computer screen when pressing it?

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics

This may sound like a pretty dumb question, but I've just found out about Newton rings and I wanted to know if the pattern of colourful circles observed in computer screens (especially old ones) when putting some sort of pressure onto them (for example, pressing it with your fingers) could actually be Newton rings. My intuition about it is that, when pressing the outer face of the screen, one could create a "convex" surface, facing the plane ones that still remain behind it, causing these fancy light effects. I don't know whether screens can act as lenses in some way, or if this effect is due to something completely unrelated. If that were the case, I would really appreciate an explanation about it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, as I asked my physical optics tutor today, such effect can plausibly be depicted as Newton rings, as what's needed for such phenomena to occur is simply for there to be 3 layers, in the next fashion:

1. A first layer in which light impacts, and that has a certain, say, n_1 refractive index, which may or may not be the same as the one in the third and last layer. It doesn't necessarily have to be a lense or anything of the sort.
2. A second layer with a **different refractive index from layer 1 and layer 3**.
3. A third layer in which Newton Rings will be formed.

Such conditions seem to be satisfied by this case scenario of the computer screen.

**However**, I can't backup my answer with formal proof or theory, so **my answer shall not stand unquestioned**. Are there any other restrictions on the refractive indexes? Does any kind of material allow for such behaviour? Is this *really* an example of Newton rings?

Other answers are very much welcome.